# 2D array column average java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have 2 arrays, `String[][] names` and `int[][] grades`, to store the names and grades of a class I am trying to print as a table in a much longer code. I was able to calculate the average of each row with a method I called in the main. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do the average of each column though. Any suggestions would be appreciated. For the row averages I wrote a method:

```
//determine average for each student
public double rowAverage(int[] rowOfGrades) {
    int total = 0;
    //sum grades for each student
    for(int grade : rowOfGrades){
        total += grade;
    }
    //return average of student grades
    return (double) total/rowOfGrades.length;
}//end getAverage
```

and then printed it in my main with

```
//creates rows and columns of text for array names and grades
    for(int student=0; student<names.length; student++) {
        System.out.printf("%s",names[student]); //student name
        for(int test : grades[student]) {
            System.out.printf("\t%7d",test); //test grades
        }

    //call method getAverage to calculate students grade average
    //pass row of grades as the argument to getAverage
    double average = rowAverage(grades[student]);
    System.out.printf("%12.2f", average);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each test you have to iterate over the students:

```
for (int test = 0; test < grades.length; test++) {
  int total  = 0;
  for(int student=0; student<names.length; student++) {
    total += grades[student][test]
  }
  double avgForTest = (double) total/names.length;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new array w/ the values for the column you are interested in; `rowAverage` will compute the average for that array (thus that column).  Repeat for each column.

Answer (score 0):

to access each column of a row you will have to access its length field e.g. `names[student].length`

example

```
int[][] towers = new int[8][8];
int myNumber=25;
for(int row=0;row<towers.length;++row)
{
    for(int column=0;column<towers[row].length;++column)
    {     
           if(myNumber==towers[row][column])
           {
              System.out.println("I found you");
              column=towers[row].length;
              row=towers.length;
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int rowSum = 0;
        int colSum = 0;
        double rowAvg = 0.0;
        double colAvg = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            rowSum += arr[i][j];
            colSum += arr[j][i];
        }
        rowAvg = rowSum / 2.0;
        colAvg = colSum / 2.0;
        System.out.println(i + " row average: " + rowAvg);
        System.out.println(i + " column average: " + colAvg);
    }
```